# Adopting Drag and Drop in a Table View / Collection View not working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop, ios11

Does anyone know why the Apple example of **Adopting Drag and Drop in a Table View** is not working on iPhone?

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Download code from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/adopting_drag_and_drop_in_a_table_view
2. Open project and change Deployment target -> Devices to Universal.
3. Run application on iPhone (simulator).
4. Try to drag some cell.

Drag and drop functionality is not working but it should behave the same way as on the iPad devices. Even the function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem]
```

is not called.

**Configuration:**

- Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235)
- Apple Swift version 4.0 (swiftlang-900.0.63 clang-900.0.37)
- Simulator Version 10.0 (SimulatorApp-829.6
  CoreSimulator-494.13.6)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`UITableView` & `UICollectionView` have `dragInteractionEnabled: Bool` instance properties.

Xcode's documentation:

> The default value of this property is true on iPad and false on iPhone. Changing the value to true on iPhone makes it possible to drag content from the table view to another app on iPhone and to receive content from other apps.

In **TableViewController.swift**, add

`tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true`

into `viewDidLoad()` (I've added it just before the `dragDelegate` and `dropDelegate` are set, and it seems to work fine).

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I intend to drag items only within the same application's table views so the documentation stays unclear.

Comment: works, thanks, do you know how to drag that cell to another tab of a tabview?

Comment: Works! The documentation is indeed unclear. For me, it was working on iPhone 11 running 16.2 but wasn't working on iPhone 8 running 14.7.1. I guess its better to set the drag property to true explicitly.